# Anybody see the problem? #Bootoast script

Tags: javascript, python, django, bootstrap-4, reference

Trying to get Bootoast to work on my website, where I try to pass a message.  You can see the code below. Using Django-bootstrap for front-end.

**BASE.HTML**

```
   <script srs="https://unpkg.com/bootoast@1.0.1/dist/bootoast.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootoast@1.0.1/dist/bootoast.min.css">

  <script>
    function toast(message, type) {
      bootoast.toast({
        position: 'bottom-center',
        message,
        type,
      });
    }

    {% if messages %}

    {% for message in messages %}
    toast('{{ message }}', '{{ message.tags }}')
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
  </script>
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
@login_required(login_url="/sign-in/?next=/customer/")
def profile_page(request):
   user_form = forms.BasicUserForm(instance=request.user)
   customer_form = forms.BasicCustomerForm(instance=request.user.customer)

   if request.method == "POST":
       user_form = forms.BasicUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
       customer_form = forms.BasicCustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.customer)

       if user_form.is_valid() and customer_form.is_valid():
           user_form.save()
           customer_form.save()

           messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been updated')
           return redirect(reverse('customer:profile'))


   return render(request, 'customer/profile.html', {
       "user_form": user_form,
       "customer_form": customer_form
   })
```

So the error I'm getting is this:

```
(index):197 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootoast is not defined
```

I'm blind or isn't this defined?

Comment: can you share the error you are getting please?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't get an error; it just won't show up, not the website.

Comment: Can you see anything in the debugger console on the browser?

Comment: I get this error:

(index):124 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootoast is not defined
    at toast ((index):124)
    at (index):134
toast @ (index):124

Answer (score 0):

```
<script srs="https://unpkg.com/bootoast@1.0.1/dist/bootoast.min.js"></script>
```

Should have been

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootoast@1.0.1/dist/bootoast.min.js"></script>
```